# UIView instance in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Assume I have two `UIViewControllers` and a`PlayerView` (`UIView Class`). And I need the`PlayerView` in both controllers.

Is there a way I could load the`PlayerView` without creating two different instances of the same class. So if I update something to the`PlayerView` in the first controller, the second controller displays the updated view.

Now, I `alloc init` PlayerView in every `UIViewController` I need the class in.

One way is to create a property of`AppDelegate` and subview it to every`UIViewController` I need, but I don't know if this is the best way to go.

Comment: What have you tried up until now to solve your problem (other than `alloc] init]`)?

Comment: I could create a property of AppDelegate and subview it to every UIViewController i need, but i don't know if this is the best way to go.

Comment: "Best practice" questions are not the best for Stack Overflow. AppDelegate is one way to have the view move from controller to controller. Others include properties and direct hierarchy access. Depending on your use case, a more concrete answer can follow. Edit your question with a specific use case, and mention what you have tried so far and has or has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow MVC (Model-View-Controller) pattern when building your apps.

In MVC, your PlayerView just have to display a state.

The state is stored in a Model (i.e. an NSObject with properties, these properties being the state of your game).

Then, you can instantiate as many PlayerView as you want or need. Just be sure to give them access (in the `init` step for instance:

```
- (instancetype) initWithState:(GameState *)<yourUniqueModelObject>
```

to your Model object so that they can display according to your game's state.

Your Model object is unique to your application and is shared across all your PlayView when needed.

Then, if you need, you can add a Controller that will handle the logic of your app/game/interface, and make the link between your Model and your View.